# How can wrong SQL statistics make a request on a 40 rows table take over a minute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

After two hours trying to figure out why my (quite simple) SQL query on a few quite empty views was taking over a minute to execute, I eventually did an "update statistics" on the impacted views, and my query instantaneously went down to a more acceptable instant result.

That being said, I find this whole statistics thing a bit weird considering that :

- the three impacted views used to return 10000+ rows, and the underlying tables had just been truncated so that the views had 40,60 and 60 rows only (the underlying tables have approximately the same number of rows)
- a select * on the three impacted views in an instantaneous operation
- joining them manually (like, in an Excel sheet) would probably have been faster than waiting for SQL server to compute the join !!
- and, last but not least, the same request on another server with the same schema, 10000+ rows, and up-to-date statistics is almost instantaneous.

I understand how bad statistics can lead to a sub-optimal execution plan. What I don't understand is how those bad statistics can lead to an execution plan THAT sub-optimal.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Edit: Unfortunately I cannot add execution plans or actual definitions here. That being said, what I'm looking for is rather an explanation of "how does SQL Server manage to take 1 minute to join 3 tables with less than a hundred rows in each, even with wrong statistics" rather than "how can I solve my specific problem", which is already done thanks to the update statistics I did.

Comment: Can you add the actual definitions please?

Comment: You will get better help with more specifics in your question? It seems that you understand statistics and query optimizer play together. So then your questions is ... ?

Comment: Nikhil: even with a stupidly inadequate exec plan, my query should have been instantaneous, because the underlying tables are so small. It's not the first time I bump this kind of behavior, so I'm curious to know what led to it. I mean, even with no indexes at all, and all the full table scans in the world, this request shouldn't have taken 1mn of cpu time on a quad core server with plenty of ram and no workload whatsoever ...

Answer (score 3):

There's a [good overview here on sql-server-performance.com](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/execution-plan-statistics/) (albeit written for SQL 2000, but the fundamental concepts won't have changed even if the detail has).

It's something I've seen before when you have a database that had a lot of rows removed from tables, and auto-stats is off. The statistics tell SQL Server the rough "spread" of the data, and have a direct impact on the optimiser as they're used to determine what indexes to use to fullfill a query and what physical operations to use to fulfill a join.

The most efficient physical join operation can depend on having up-to-date stats, and using the wrong operator can have fairly catastrophic effects. Similarly it may decide to lazy spool when it doesn't need to (etc). When I've seen it this behaviour, I've seen SQL Server invoke parallelism with some funny index choices to handle only a few hundred rows.

Answer (score 0):

How many records are returned by the views involved is not important. The interesting part is: how many records are in the underlying tables? For normal views, SQL Server will expand them when compiling the query plan, so instead of running each individually it builds one big new execution plan as if whatever is done in the views is part of your query...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with SQL Server 2008 because I have noticed this a lot myself, and have never had to manually update statistics with earlier versions of SQL Server. I often have queries in newer versions of SQL Server that work extremely fast for a while, then suddenly fail. Below is an example of a query that takes seconds to run and all of a sudden it stops working - it will sit for days and not complete. I eventually figured out (after a lot of time and effort) that all I have to do is manually update statistics on the SMALLEST table, and performance goes back to normal. So this runs smoothly for several production runs, then suddenly it no longer works (no code changes, no data changes), then I manually update statistics and all goes back to usual. I feel like I'm working with Oracle now - code that worked in seconds suddenly takes forever - analyse all tables and it's fixed. I feel that the newer versions of SQL Server have suddenly started working like Oracle (not good in my opinion). I think it should be reported as a bug. We should not have to manually update statistics in SQL Server.

```
Select DISTINCT
c.claim_number,
c.claim_number_type,
'SERVICE_ID',
ds.data_source_id
From db1.dbo.std_claim c with (nolock)
Join db2.dbo.source_manager sm with (nolock) on sm.etl_source_id = c.etl_source_id
Join db3.dbo.data_source ds with (nolock) on ds.data_source=c.data_source     
and ds.tenant_id = sm.tenant_id
Where ISNULL(sm.processed_flag,'N') = 'N'
And sm.active_flag = 'Y'
And c.deleted_ind = 'N'
And not exists (Select 1 
From db3.dbo.id_map im
Where im.ID_NAME = 'SERVICE_ID' 
And im.data_source_id = ds.data_source_id
And im.src_id = c.claim_number
And im.src_id_type = c.claim_number_type)
Group By c.claim_number, 
c.claim_number_type, 
ds.data_source_id
```