# Optimizer not using optimal indexes for the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query which is returning high Logical reads, CPU time, and waits. It was running absolutely fine until last week.

I tried option recompile/maxdop, and even cleared the plan for this single query from plan cache using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. Yet, SQL Server didn't use the optimal plan/indexes for this query.

However, when I use index hints, the performance improved significantly - (I am fully aware of index hints implications in live, hence, don't want to use them).

Just wondering if you could guide me in the direction where I can make SQL server use the right indexes without the use of index hints in the query.

**[*Original query - Performing poorly as SQL Server not using the optimal index*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYDvi.png)**

```
SELECT  oh.shipopt
FROM dbo.orderhash oh
INNER JOIN dbo.orderaddress oa ON oh.sessionid = oa.sessionid AND oa.addresstype = 's'
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (1) soo.shippingoptions_rsn_alt ,soo.id
            FROM dbo.shippingoptions_override soo 
            WHERE  soo.shippingoptions_rsn = oh.shipopt
                    AND ((oh.shippingweight >= soo.threshold_from AND soo.threshold_type = 'WEIGHT')
                        OR (oh.hashtotal >= soo.threshold_from AND soo.threshold_type = 'PRICE'))
                 AND soo.active = 1
                 --Check Post restrictions
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.shippingoptions_postcode sp 
                                 WHERE soo.shippingoptions_rsn_alt =sp.shippingoptions_rsn 
                                 AND sp.postcode_area = LEFT(oa.postcode,LEN(sp.postcode_area)))
            ORDER BY soo.threshold_from DESC ,soo.rnk ASC
            )sho 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.adyen a /*WITH (INDEX = IX_adyen_sessionid__success__processed__userid__authResult__INC)*/ WHERE oh.sessionid = a .sessionid AND a.processed = 1 AND a.success =1 AND a.paymentMethod = 'KLARNA')   
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NAV_order navo WHERE oh.sessionid=navo.session_id AND navo.status_id = 0 AND navo.NAV_prepush_status_id = 0);
```

[***Query with Index hints - Improved performance***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80vsX.png)

```
SELECT  oh.shipopt
FROM dbo.orderhash oh WITH (INDEX = IX_sessionid_orderhash_INCL_status_printref)
INNER JOIN dbo.orderaddress oa WITH (INDEX = IX_orderaddress__sessionid__INC__addresstype) ON oh.sessionid = oa.sessionid AND oa.addresstype = 's'
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (1) soo.shippingoptions_rsn_alt ,soo.id
            FROM dbo.shippingoptions_override soo 
            WHERE  soo.shippingoptions_rsn = oh.shipopt
                    AND ((oh.shippingweight >= soo.threshold_from AND soo.threshold_type = 'WEIGHT')
                        OR (oh.hashtotal >= soo.threshold_from AND soo.threshold_type = 'PRICE'))
                 AND soo.active = 1
                 --Check Post restrictions
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.shippingoptions_postcode sp 
                                 WHERE soo.shippingoptions_rsn_alt =sp.shippingoptions_rsn 
                                 AND sp.postcode_area = LEFT(oa.postcode,LEN(sp.postcode_area)))
            ORDER BY soo.threshold_from DESC ,soo.rnk ASC
            )sho 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.adyen a WHERE oh.sessionid = a .sessionid AND a.processed = 1 AND a.success =1 AND a.paymentMethod = 'KLARNA')  
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NAV_order navo WHERE oh.sessionid=navo.session_id AND navo.status_id = 0 AND navo.NAV_prepush_status_id = 0);
```

Comment: have you had large volume changes on data within any of the tables?  maybe table statistics need a refresh?  Optimizer uses table statistics when determining a plan; if those are not representative of actual it can result in sub optimal plans. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471661/how-can-wrong-sql-statistics-make-a-request-on-a-40-rows-table-take-over-a-minut?rq=1 or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273176/which-sql-table-statistics-are-used-after-they-are-updated-when-norecompute-is-t

Comment: What index are you using? I would start by addin `dbo.shippingoptions_postcode (shippingoptions_rsn, sp.postcode_area)`. I would also rephrase the `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` as an anti-join.

Comment: Please see the index in the second query, thanks